# Can't get key value as String from metadata

Tags: swift3, metadata, mpmediaitem, mpmediaplayercontroller, nscfnumber

I'm grabbing metadata from an MPMediaItem like this:

```
let url = item.value(forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url! as URL, options: nil)
let metaArray = asset.metadata
for metadata in metaArray{
    print("-----metadata:\(metadata)")
    print("-----metadata.key:\(String(describing: metadata.key))")
}
```

However, when I get a block of metadata printed the "key" is printed as a numeric value instead of "pcst" as shown in the printout:

`-----metadata:<AVMetadataItem: 0x1740153f0, identifier=itsk/pcst, keySpace=itsk, key class = __NSCFNumber, key=pcst, commonKey=(null), extendedLanguageTag=(null), dataType=com.apple.metadata.datatype.int8, time={INVALID}, duration={INVALID}, startDate=(null), extras={
    dataLength = 1;
    dataType = 21;
    dataTypeNamespace = "com.apple.itunes";
}, value=1>
-----metadata.key:Optional(1885565812)`

This is happening for all of the metadata/keys (there are 29 in this particular media item).

Also note that this line of code:

```
let realString = NSString(string: metadata.key! as! String)
```

causes this error:
`Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1b80dcdf0) to 'NSString' (0x1b80edae8).`

How can I get the string value for the key ("pcst") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be what you are looking for is [`identifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avmetadataitem/1386968-identifier) property of `AVMetadataItem`.

```
for metadata in metaArray{
    print(metadata.identifier ?? "DefaultValue")       
}
```

Comment: It looks like it will work - I just have to parse the string to remove the chars before the "/", remove the "/" and the 4 chars that follow....

Comment: @wayneh You can use `components(separatedBy:)` with `/` and access the last object from result

Comment: Got an easy way to strip characters from a string?

Comment: @wayneh There are too many ways, like one I have already suggested in my last comment you can also use subscripting by finding `/` index using `range(of:)` method

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something simple like in Java, C#, and so many other languages...  :)

Comment: I mean that Java and other languages make it a lot easier to parse strings and work with substrings (for example) than with Swift and all the indexes....

Comment: I just got it working - the `identifier` is easier to work with since it's a plain string - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, I feel pretty stupid for missing that...I've stared at the metadata for many hours...D'oh!

Comment: @wayneh It happens :)

Comment: I've got several other difficult questions if you are bored...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case others want to see the code I'm using:

```
func returnKeyString(_ inVal: String)->String{
    // expecting the metadata for "identifier" as input - returns key value
    // eg "itsk/ldes" ->  "ldes"
    // or "id3/%00WFD" etc.  -> "wfd"
    var sFinal:String = ""

    if (inVal.contains("/")){
        sFinal = (inVal.components(separatedBy: "/")[1])
    }
    if sFinal.contains("%"){
        sFinal = sFinal.components(separatedBy: "%")[1]
        let index1 = sFinal.index(sFinal.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
        sFinal = sFinal.substring(from: index1)
    }
    return sFinal.lowercased()
}
```